# How to replace every comma with a new word from a file

Tags: bash

I have a log file samplelog.log

```
 [java] 08 May 2017 21:17:37,508  INFO FoobarTests.testSomething.95e0dc44-c51e-4b2f-a048-eba70eae6d94-60e04794-2fe8-42c6-b8a3-5ea180a20431 aaaa.aaa.test.:170 - Creating account: aaaa.aaaa.test.client.FoobarSpec@4a0e091e[name=<null>,aaaa=33,bbb=<null>,ccc=<null>,ddd=<null>,xxx=XY,eeee=eee,fff=fff,port=8200,

 [java] 08 May 2017 21:17:40,527  INFO FoobarTests.testSomething.95e0dc44-c51e-4b2f-a048-eba70eae6d94-60e04794-2fe8-42c6-b8a3-5ea180a20431 aaa.bbb.test.runner.ClientFactory:400 - Building a client for customer[123] using url-info[test.client.utils.Endpoint@78830d9a[envn=aaa,endPoint=<null>]].
```

I want to loop through this file colors.cfg

```
\033[0;31
\033[0;32
\033[0;33
\033[0;34
\033[0;35
\033[0;36
\033[0;37
```

and replace every comma in the log file with "a comma and a line from the color.cfg". A different line is read everytime.

I want to use this to give text a different color after every comma in the logfile.

so i get output like this in a new file.

```
 [java] 08 May 2017 21:17:37,508  INFO FoobarTests.testSomething.95e0dc44-c51e-4b2f-a048-eba70eae6d94-60e04794-2fe8-42c6-b8a3-5ea180a20431 aaaa.aaa.test.:170 - Creating account: aaaa.aaaa.test.client.FoobarSpec@4a0e091e[name=<null>,\033[0;31aaaa=33,\033[0;37bbb=<null>,\033[0;36ccc=<null>,\033[0;35ddd=<null>,\033[0;34xxx=XY,\033[0;33eeee=eee,\033[0;32fff=fff,\033[0;31port=8200,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COLORS=()
while read -r line; do
  COLORS+=("${line}")
done </path/to/colors_file/colors_file.txt

IFS=','

while read -r logLine; do
  logLineParsed=''
  clrsIndx=0

  for linePart in ${logLine}; do
    if [ "${clrsIndx}" -eq "${#COLORS[@]}" ]; then
      clrsIndx=0
    fi

    logLineParsed+="${linePart},${COLORS[${clrsIndx}]}"
    ((clrsIndx++))
  done

  printf '%s\n\n' "${logLineParsed}" >> new_log_file.txt
done </path/to/log_file/log_file.txt
```

Output:

```
[java] 08 May 2017 21:17:37,\033[0;31508  INFO FoobarTests.testSomething.95e0dc44-c51e-4b2f-a048-eba70eae6d94-60e04794-2fe8-42c6-b8a3-5ea180a20431 aaaa.aaa.test.:170 - Creating account: aaaa.aaaa.test.client.FoobarSpec@4a0e091e[name=<null>,\033[0;32aaaa=33,\033[0;33bbb=<null>,\033[0;34ccc=<null>,\033[0;35ddd=<null>,\033[0;36xxx=XY,\033[0;31eeee=eee,\033[0;32fff=fff,\033[0;33port=8200,\033[0;34

[java] 08 May 2017 21:17:40,\033[0;31527  INFO FoobarTests.testSomething.95e0dc44-c51e-4b2f-a048-eba70eae6d94-60e04794-2fe8-42c6-b8a3-5ea180a20431 aaa.bbb.test.runner.ClientFactory:400 - Building a client for customer[123] using url-info[test.client.utils.Endpoint@78830d9a[envn=aaa,\033[0;32endPoint=<null>]].,\033[0;33
```